# Compare one column for all rows when another column matches

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I would like to have a formula that does this: for all of the same values in column B, look to column C, and then let me know if the values are different in column C. I have tried a couple things but nothing seems to be working properly. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Here is an example of what the sheet looks like]

Basically I have a bunch of mice (column A) in different cages (column B) with different genders (column C). I would like to be able to quantify if the genders in column C are the same or different for all the mice in the same cage (column B).

All of the logical arguments I have tried only compare 2 cells and I have not found any that can compare more than 2 cells in google sheets.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. How are "same" values in column A defined.  Do the values in Column B have to be on the same row? it would be great if you could show us how your data looks like, your desired result and what you already tried (as Stackoverflow is not a code writing service)

Comment: I just updated my original question to reflect your questions and make it more clear as to what I am looking for, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this visually would be making a pivot table of the table.

formulaic in the same table you can append to column D for every row, starting in D2 and dragging down:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$14, B2) = COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$14, B2, $C$2:$C$14, C2)
```

which counts the number of mice per cage and compares it to the number of mice in the cage of that gender.

If you have a list with the cage numbers you can apply the same formula there and just check for one gender:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$14, B18) = COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$14, B18, $C$2:$C$14, "♂")
```

Comment: That almost works, but that gives you the number of mice in a cage and compared it to the total number of males or females, and not the number of males or females in that cage.

Comment: It worked for me, is the order of columns different in your worksheet? It runs the comparison on the Cage (Column B) and adds the criterion of Gender to the second count it compares against (Column C).

Comment: Well in the example I showed there are 6 females and 7 males, if I understand your formula correctly, for row 2, it will compare the value of 3 mice in cage 1 with the value of 6 females. For your formula to work you would want cage 1 to show 3 mice but 2 females for false, but row 5 (cage 2) to show 2 mice and 2 males so true.

Comment: `COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$14, B2)` Counts the number of mice in the cage of the current mouse.  `COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$14, B2, $C$2:$C$14, C2)` Counts all mice in the same cage as the current one with the additional limitation that they have to be the same gender as the current one.   The bottom formula is doing the same it just always checks for one gender. In your example the only cage returning true for having only one gender is cage 2 which this formula does.